# gcc compiler lib file not found error

Tags: gcc, ada, gcov, gnat, gnat-gps

Please help me on the gcc compiler command

gcc -c -ID:\pjtName\lib -c -fprofile-arcs -ftest-coverage D:\pjtName\source\tmp.ada

I am trying to compile the tmp.ada with coverage. adb and ads files are located in D:\pjtName\source folder.  and my lib files are located in D:\pjtName\lib folder.

The problem is gcc is not locates tmp.ads file and the library files in the D:\pjtName\lib folder. it show file not found error

after this command i need to run gcov command for the tmp.ada file

Answer (score 2):

GNAT’s build process is complicated. `gcc` is really too low-level a tool to use easily; instead, use `gnatmake` and GNAT project files.

You’ve tagged *gnat-gps*, so I assume you actually have GPS. If that’s so, your best bet would be, when opening GPS, to select *Create new project with wizard* and go on from there. If you get stuck, use GPS’s included help or come back here.

To get coverage information with GPS, you go to *Edit* / *Edit Project Properties* and

- in the *Ada* tab, select *Code coverage* and *Instrument arcs*, which includes `-ftest-coverage` and `-fprofile-arcs`;
- in the *Ada Linker* tab, select *Code coverage*, which includes `-fprofile-generate` (you get link time errors otherwise).

By the way, you mention a file `tmp.ada`; it’s best to stick with `.ads` for specs and `.adb` for bodies. GNAT does its best, but if your other code includes `with Tmp;` GNAT will look for `tmp.ads`. You can [alter this behaviour](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gnat_ugn_unw/Arbitrary-File-Naming-Conventions.html), but why bother unless you have to for other reasons!

Comment: thanks Simon Wright, The GPS tool shows "could not create gcno file" error when use gprbuild tool with my "pjt.gpr" file. even though my gpr file have the -fprofile-arcs -ftest-coverage as default switches it's not generating the coverage files. So, that i have choosen the gcc tool to create .gcda and .gcno files for my ada source files.

Comment: Added something on getting coverage with GPS.

Comment: I don’t understand why it would say “could not generate gcno file”! For me, the program failed to link without `-fprofile-generate`.

Answer (score 0):

As was stated above, don't use gcc.

I usually use `gnat compile filename.adb` then use `gnat bind filename.ali`, then `gnat link filename.ali -Lexternaldirectory -lexternallib`